# Upgrading google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a google drive API that has become depreciated and is no longer working.  The error message that I receive is "ReferenceError: "DocsList" is not defined".  The code is as follows:

```
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
```

I tried to replace it with this:

```
var copyId = get /files/fileId (docTemplate)
```

But it tells me that "get" is not defined.

I am getting my information from  [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please check this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) instead.The [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById%28String%29) method exists in this newer class.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for that suggestion.  I replaced DocsList with DriveApp so the script looked like this:

    var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)

and everything is working now.  Thanks again for the help.

Paul